# Create a compound Key including a lookup value

Tags: ms-access

I have not used access for many years, but need what I thought was a simple DB and struggling at early stage.

I have a table that represents objects that can belong to multiple systems and may have some different attributes between the systems.

So my initial idea was to have a table for `Systems`, a table for `Objects`, and a child table for `Object Attributes`.

My `Objects` table currently is 3 fields:

> - **Key** : Autogenerated
> - **Object Name** : Text
> - **System** : Lookup to system table

`Object Name` will not be unique as it can appear in multiple systems, so I want to create a unique compound key of the `Object Name` & `System` field.  This key will be what joins this table to the child `Object Attributes` table.

My problem is that the `System` lookup field does not appear in the available fields to use when trying to create a compound key.

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: As per the adventure of a developer here: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/536286-lookups-composite-primary-keys-how the answer seems to be a resounding "Don't do that".  Also see commandment 2 here: http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm

Comment: Nice links and luckily I asked this at the start of any development and have corrected my approach, thanks